# Opennebula CoreOS cloud-config

Tags: ssh, passwords, cloud-init, coreos, opennebula

I have a coreos_production_rackspace_image running on opennebula 4.6.2 under a xen hypervisor which I can connect to via ssh from the coomand line but I cannot login to the running coreos vm because I don't know how to setup a password via cloud-init.

In opennebula there is a was to pass ssh keys to a vM via a context variable:
"SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA....." but this does not allow me to login (not sure why). I have even uploaded a cloud-init file to the "files & Kernals" which I pass  to the vm via a context variable to the vm template and I still cannot login.

Opennebula does have a concept of cloud-init, but it says it sets up the root password and not the core user password. http://docs.opennebula.org/4.6/user/virtual_machine_setup/cloud-init.html

Answer (score 0):

In the CoreOS AWS EC2 images, openssh is setup and asks which keypair you want to use to login. So, maybe you should switch to Amazon from Rackspace.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated a CoreOS image to the OpenNebula Marketplace:

http://marketplace.opennebula.systems/appliance/570151808fb81d0d6f000002

The hypervisor is KVM, not Xen, though.